# HTML/CSS/SVG button not clickable.

Tags: css, html, svg

```
<a class="round-button2" href="index.html" >
<img src="images/Palette.svg" alt="Palette" />
</a> 
<a class="round-button3" href="index2.html" >
<img src="images/Chef.svg" alt="Chef" />    
</a>
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1496aL5TpiqSO4pIh81wkq41Gn02OppE1 is the link for the svgs
https://codeitdown.com/css-round-buttons/ is a tutorial I followed; I recognize that its a 4 year old article; it maybe outdated. I was hoping that the community would be able to help.

I can get the svgs/circles to appear but they are not clickable to the index links I need them to go to. Im a novice coder/html user. I ran this in Adobe Dreamweaver.

## CSS/style

```
.round-button2 {
width: 6%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 6%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background: #464646;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button2:hover #shape{
background: #262626;
}
.round-button2 img {
display: block;
width: 90%;
padding: 20%;
height: auto;
}
    
.round-button3 {
width: 6%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 6%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background: #464646;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button3:hover #shape{
background: #262626;
}
.round-button3 img {
display: block;
width: 90%;
padding-bottom: 15%;
padding-left: 20%;
padding-right: 12%;
padding-top: 20%;
height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `width` to `max-width 70%;` with `img` classes.
and `a` class need correct width and height to be clickable.
check this fiddle (based your code and that guide).

http://jsfiddle.net/maxofpower/Jyjjx/13886/

```css
.round-button {
    width: 10%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #464646;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button:hover {
    background: #262626;
}
.round-button img {
    display: block;
    width: 76%;
    padding: 12%;
    height: auto;
}

.round-button2 {
width: 6%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 6%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background: #464646;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button2:hover #shape{
background-color: #262626;
}

.round-button2 img{
display: block;
max-width: 70%;
height: auto;
padding:5px 8px 0;
}
.round-button3 img 
{
  display: block;
max-width: 70%;
height: auto;
padding:10px ;
}
.round-button3 {
width: 6%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 6%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background: #464646;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button3:hover #shape{
background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-button">
    <a href="http://example.com">
        <img src="http://codeitdown.com/media/Home_Icon.svg" alt="Home" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="round-button2">
<a   href="index2.html" >
<img id=shape src="https://svgur.com/i/8as.svg" alt="pallete" />    
</a>
</div>

<div class="round-button3">
<a   href="index2.html" >
<img id=shape src="https://svgur.com/i/8bu.svg" alt="Chef" />    
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This was fixed by adding z-index: 100;